# 50VA Transformer HRC Fuse Selection maths

Tags: power-supply, transformer, fuses

How do I select HRC fuses for the primary mains input of a 50VA Toroidal Transformer? Trying to design an EMC filter for the primary side of the transformer and planning to implement two HRC fuses for both the mains live and neutral wires. But not sure what specifications for the HRC fuse I will be needing for best approach. How should I calculate the current, time delay etc. for the fuses. Also, which brand HRC fuses are the best in market for this particular application? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Not a good idea to use two fuses one in live and one in neutral because a failure in the neutral fuse might cause someone to try and fix the problem and get electrocuted by inadvertently touching the intact live circuits.

Comment: And in some (most?) jurisdictions, fusing neutral is illegal for precisely that reason.

Comment: Some good branded power supplies like Rohde & Schwarz have dual HRC fuses on both live and neutral. So, these power supplies are breaking laws?